# Execute Function after page changes

Tags: javascript, jquery, google-chrome, google-chrome-extension, page-refresh

How can I execute a javascript function after the page has changed after a refresh? Is it even possible? If not should be possible with keywords...
Edit: I want to use it in a chrome extension.

Thanks for the help of this great community!

Comment: could you define "changed"?

Comment: Text on the page or the whole structue (not a single node)

Comment: As it seems to me, the only way is to bind to every single event... This is the way angular 2 detects changes of its own. If you don't like it, look periodically at innerHTML of body

Comment: Thank you, I found an extension which stops refreshing when a keyword is detected. My extension will start automatically when its on th eright page. This is it https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/auto-refresh-plus/ohfjpkccecpdfkpmfocndhepolhljfhg?hl=en

Comment: There is [an answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/39508954/3773011) on the proposed duplicate that specifically covers the expanded options in a Chrome extension.